# error: placement-in expression syntax is experimental and subject to change. (see issue #27779)

Tags: rust

I am following [Rust By Example](https://rustbyexample.com/flow_control/if_else.html) and am getting an error which I am not sure how to address:

```
fn main() {
    let x: f32 = 10.;

    if (x == 10) {
        println!("if");
    } else if (x > 10) && (x<-5) {
        println!("else if");
    } else {
        println!("else");
    }
}
```

The compiling error below looks to be as a results of the `else if`. How do perform two conditional checks in the `else if` and why is it not working?

```
error: placement-in expression syntax is experimental and subject to change. (see issue #27779)
 --> src/main.rs:6:28
  |
6 |     } else if (x > 10) && (x<-5) {
  |                            ^^^^
```

Comment: Reminded me of [this classic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-operator-in-c).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you are writing `x<-5` instead of `x < -5` with whitespaces, Rust sees `<-` as [the placement operator](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/27779). Putting whitespace around your operators would in general be best, since it fixes this and also improved readability a lot.